# Oracle Forms Builder input validation :number with up to two decimal places

Tags: oracle, validation, input, oracleforms

In the Oracle form builder, there is a text box where I am taking input from the user. The input has to be a number (float) but it should not allow after two decimal places. Tried adding an alert after giving input but it should be such that the cursor won't go further after two decimal places. Can anyone help?? I can provide more details if this is not clear.
So when a trigger is added so that when we enter a wrong number, it shows the invalid message as it should. The problem is when I try to "CLEAR" the value using a button which is added to clear all the values,  it still shows Invalid number alert.

Comment: Have you tried to use a format mask? (Under _data_ property group of text item)

Comment: Yes. Actually I have used format mask and implemented an alert. What it does is after entering the input and clicking on next, it shows invalid alert. But what i want is while giving input it shouldn't allow more than 2 decimals i.e. I don't want to click on next and then alert to show up. If you know what I mean

Comment: Thanks for the quick response though

Comment: So what is happening actually is that when I am entering an invalid number and then clicking on "CLEAR" button, the invalid alert is showing up.

Comment: Ok, could you please modify your question to add what you said? For more clarification

Answer (score 1):

Forms can't do that by itself. It validates item value once you leave the item, not while you're typing a value into it, as something has to "trigger" validation. We usually use `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` triggers for that but - as you noticed - in this case you don't even need a trigger as format mask does the job.

If you'd want to restrict number of decimal digits at time of typing, I believe you'll have to use some Java code, i.e. PJC (Pluggable Java Component) or Java Beans. As I don't know Java, I can't assist with code I'd write for you, but - have a look at [Oracle Forms Community - Pluggable Java Components & Java Beans' library](http://forms.pjc.bean.over-blog.com/), maybe you'll find something useful.